# Android - how to intercept links inside iframe(webview) and check it is fully loaded or not

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe, webview

I am loading the www folder created using ionic inside a webview in android.Inside the webview I am using iframe for loading some html.Everything is working fine,But not able to intercept the hyperlink inside iframe and unable to check whether it is fully loaded or not.

Here is my activity code,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activity = MainActivity.this;
     webview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     webViewConfiguration();
     setWebViewListner();
     webview.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
}

private void setWebViewListner() {
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){   

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


            if(url.startsWith("tel://")) {
                Tel=url.replace("//", "");
                Log.d("*** url with removed // ***",Tel);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(Tel));
                startActivity(intent); 
                return true;
            }
            else
             return false;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           webview.loadUrl("javascript:invokeController("+true+")");
           Log.d("*** on page finished ***",url);


        }
    });
}
private void webViewConfiguration() {
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
     webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
     webview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "javaScriptToJava");
     webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }

        webview.loadUrl(Url);
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void nativeBackButton() {
    finish();
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void keyBoardClose(){
    if (imm!=null) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:callBackIonic()");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

shouldOverrideUrlLoading is getting triggered if the href link inside iframe is tel://../../ or file:///android_asset/../../ but it is not getting triggered, if it is a http Request.

I want to put a loader for each and every link pressed inside the iframe.

Can anyone say if there is a way to handle http hyperlink inside iframe in a webview.

EDIT:
I replaced the iframe inside my html using ng-bind-html/ng-include and I am able to intercept the links and onPageFinished function as well.But the styling and some other stuffs are not applied if I use ng-bind-html/ng-include. How to get it working with the help of iFrame.why on using iframe inside webview does not invoke shouldoverrideurlloading.

Answer (score 1):

Use shouldInterceptRequest of WebViewClient. You can intercept iframe source.

```
API level 11
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url){
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
}

API level 21
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) 
{
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
}
```